# if P=NP, then is E=NE?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

If the computational complexity class P equals to NP, does the complexity class E equal to the class NE?

E is defined as $DTIME(O(2^{O(n)}))$
NE is defined as $NTIME(O(2^{O(n)}))$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, by using the padding argument.  The [Wikipedia article on the padding argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument) contains a proof of the implication P=NP ⇒ EXP=NEXP, and the implication P=NP ⇒ E=NE can be proved in the same way.  I leave the details as an exercise.